# How to count a feature x if y condition is true (bigquery)

Tags: sql, r, machine-learning, google-bigquery

I am new in machine learning and I am running one of my first machine learning problems. I do a lot of research by myself but could not find the solution for this question.

I am creating new variables from my dataset in Bigquery. One of the variables consists in count a variable (x) if a condition in variable (y) is met. I cannot use WHERE or HAVING since the condition is only related to the calculation of this specific variable.

The code is more or less like this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT sessionid IF(date > “2018-06-01” && date < “2018-06-30”)) 
AS sessions_lastmonth
```

I know that this code is not correct and could not be but is just a way to express more or less what I need.
The goal is to know the number of sessions in a certain period. I cannot use the count for date because in one day you can have more than one session and not every row is a different session (a session can have several lines because the user can go through many pages in the same session).

Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(date >= '2018-06-01' AND date <= '2018-06-30', sessionid, NULL)) AS sessions_lastmonth
```

Comment: Mikhail, thank you very much! The code worked perfectly!
BTW, this code is super handy for many other calculations too!

Comment: Note that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` ignores null values.

Comment: so, that is exactly the reason for having NULL there - so it gets not counted :o)

Answer (score 3):

You said you couldn't use `WHERE` so I am going to assume that the answer that proposes you use `WHERE` won't fly?

I think you might need to use `CASE` instead, so your query might look something like:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN date > “2018-06-01” AND date < “2018-06-30” THEN sessionid ELSE NULL END) AS sessions_lastmonth
```

That syntax might not be right, but it might help you onto the right track?

Comment: Hi Richard, this one works too! Thank you so much! Pretty handy!